# Xamarin - Hardware detection using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a cross-platform application that are using sensors of the device. 
I know I can use the SensorManager in the android sub-project to detect if the android device has the needed hardware to run the application, is there something similar in Xamarin.Forms that I can use instead of writing platform specific code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you need? 
Maybe Xamarin.Essentials has all what you need :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/

Comment: @Liran ben david Are there any update?